# Flet telethon login page is not working (async)

Tags: python, asynchronous, telethon, flet

I am programming Telegram Login page with Flet Gui and Telethon module. The problem I am facing is the code is not sending verification code to entered phone number nor showing any error it just stops at `await client.send_code_request(phone_number)`. I expect the code to send code to specified number

```py
# you can get telegram development credentials in telegram API Development Tools
api_id = ""
api_hash = ""

client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash)

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "Tel"

    def startup_async():
        new_event_loop().run_until_complete(startup())

    def get_verif_async(phone_num):
        print('ciao')
        new_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_verification_code(phone_num))
    
    def set_verif_async(phone_number, code_num):
        print('Line 25 \n phone: ' + phone_number + " code: " + code_num)
        new_event_loop().run_until_complete(set_verification_code(phone_number, code_num))
        
    async def get_verification_code(phone_number):
        print("29 " + phone_number)
        
        if phone_number and re.match(r"^\+\d+$", phone_number):
            print("31")
            if not await client.is_user_authorized():
                await client.send_code_request(phone_number)
                page.go("/code_screen") 
        else:
            print(36)
            page.add(ft.Text(value='error'))        
        #view.update()

    async def set_verification_code(phone_number, code_number):
        print("42")
        await client.sign_in(phone_number, code_number)
        page.go("/homepage")  
          
    async def startup():
        print('startup')
        await client.connect()
        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            page.route = "/login_screen"
        else:
            page.route = "/homepage"    


    def route_change(e):
        page.views.clear()

        if page.route == "/login_screen":
            global phone_num_field
            phone_num_field = ft.TextField(hint_text="Your phone number", expand=True)
            page.views.append(
                View(
                    "/login_screen",
                    [
                        AppBar(title=Text("Login"), bgcolor=colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                        phone_num_field,
                        #ElevatedButton(text='Get code', on_click= get_verif_async(phone_num_field.value)),
                        ElevatedButton(text='Get code', on_click=lambda x: get_verif_async(phone_num_field.value))                       
                    ],
                )
            )
            
        
        if page.route == "/code_screen":
            code_field = ft.TextField(hint_text="code", expand=True)
            page.views.append(
                View(
                    "/code_screen",
                    [
                        AppBar(title=Text("Code"), bgcolor=colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                        code_field,
                        phone_num_field,
                        #ElevatedButton(text='Get code', on_click= get_verif_async(phone_num_field.value)),
                        ElevatedButton(text='Enter code', on_click=lambda x: set_verif_async(phone_num_field.value, code_field.value)),
                        ElevatedButton(text='Back', on_click=lambda x: page.go("/login_screen"))                      
                    ],
                )
            )
          
        if page.route == "/homepage":
            page.views.append(
                View(
                    "/homepage",
                    [
                        AppBar(title=Text("homepage"), bgcolor=colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                    ],
                )
            )


        page.update()

    def view_pop(e):
        page.views.pop()
        top_view = page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

    # async script startup
    startup_async()

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop

    page.go(page.route)


ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include the code. Click [edit] and add it - making sure that what you provide is a [mre].

Comment: Telethon won't work correctly if you keep recreating the `asyncio` event loop every single time. Make sure to always use the same loop while Telethon is connected, since connections are bound to a specific loop and won't work otherwise.